# Error in monitoring WebSphere portal threadpool using check_was Nagios plugin

Tags: websphere, nagios, websphere-portal

I have installed WebSphere Portal 8.5 version on CentOS 7 . I am trying to monitor various portal parameters like heap memory , live sessions , threadpools etc . For monitoring , I am using Nagios .For this , I have installed latest version of 'check_was' nagios plugin . I am able to monitor heap memory and live sessions but I am not able to monitor thread pools . Whenever , I am firing the reqd command to check 'threadpool' , I am getting the following error ----

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_was-0.4/check_was  -s threadpool -w 80 -c 90 -p WebSphere_Portal
ERROR - Failed to get stats object on WebSphere:cell=Cell85,mbeanIdentifier=null,name=server.startup,node=Node85,platform=dynamicproxy,process=WebSphere_Portal,spec=1.0,type=ThreadPool,version=8.5.5.2.

Can anybody help me in this ?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are missing to enable PMI.  Take a look on bellow link:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tprf_prfstartadmin.html

How to enable PMI:

Procedure

```
Open the administrative console.
Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name.
Click the Configuration tab.
Click Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) under Performance.
Select the Enable Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) check box.
Optionally, select the check box Use sequential counter updates to enable precise statistic update.
Optionally, choose a statistic set that needs to be monitored under Currently Monitored Statistic Set.
Optionally, click on Custom to selectively enable or disable statistics. Choose a component from the tree and enable or disable statistics on the opposite table. Go back to the main PMI configuration page by clicking the Performance Monitoring Infrastructure link.
Click Apply or OK.
Click Save.
Restart the application server. The changes you make will not take effect until you restart the application server.
Note: When Intelligent Management is enabled, the application server does not let you disable PMI counters that the Intelligent Management requires. For information about the list of PMI counters that cannot be disabled when Intelligent Management is enabled, see Enabling PMI data collection.
```

Regards!

Comment: As per your suggestion , I enabled PMI . In currently monitored statistic set , I selected option ' ALL ' . After that , I restarted portal . But even after that , it is giving me the same error .